# ui bootstrap tooltip enable when input is disabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Hello I want my tooltip to appears whenever **input[submit]** is disabled. Disabling input works very well it is disabled when inputs[text] are invalid but tooltips doesn't shows.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="submit"
       form="loginData"
       ng-disabled="loginData.login.$invalid || loginData.password.$invalid"
       class="btn btn-primary btn-md"
       ng-click="$ctrl.login()"
       value="Zaloguj"
       uib-tooltip="Wypełnij formularz!"
       tooltip-placement="top"
       tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'"
       tooltip-append-to-body="true"
       tooltip-enable="loginData.login.$invalid || loginData.password.$invalid" />
```

**tooltip-enable** directive should make tooltip enabled when input login or password are invalid but it doesn't work, please quick help!

EDIT: 
I was working with google chrome so I didn't realize that this solution actually works in others browsers (mozilla for sure). But still it doesn't work with newest google chrome so it is not satisfactory enough.

Summarizing the new question is how to walk around that issue in google chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***HTML elements with disabled attribute do not fire events.*** 
But don't worry, you can use a simple **div/span** with `uib-tooltip` directive as **wrapper** of the disabled input/button.

In your case you want to show the tooltip only when is disabed, so try the following... ([PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Lo5nREbWVL70jAauvpp?p=preview))

**HTML**

```
<span uib-tooltip="Demo tooltip" 
      tooltip-enable="isBtnDisabled" 
      ng-class="{'my-tooltip': isDisabled}">
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="isDisabled" class="btn btn-info" value="My btn">
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}

.my-tooltip input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```